# Looking for a JavaScript array insert method

Tags: javascript

To update an element of an array at a specific index. I want to replace the index 1 with the object's id, value remains unchanged.

```
const Obj = {
  id: 10,
  value: "Extra stuff"
}

const Array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "Val 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "Val 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "Val 3"
  },
]
```

Expected result should be:

```
const Array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "Val 1"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    value: "Val 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "Val 3"
  },
]
```

Tried this, but it's incomplete:

```
  const newArray = [...Array.slice(0,1), Obj.id, ...Array.slice(1)]
  console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.splice()` see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: _"I want to replace the index 1 with the object, updating its ID only"_ - What is it now? Replace the object, or update the id of that object? How is `[..., Obj.id, ...]` supposed to _"update"_ an id? Do you need to preserve the original array?

Comment: `const Array = []` - its a terrible idea to overwrite a built-in type with an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix for the issue that you are facing with.

Create a new array with below logic. That will create a new array with your requiremnet correctly..

```
[...myArray.slice(0, 1), { ...myArray[1], ...{id: myObj.id}}, ...myArray.slice(2)]
```

```js
const myObj = {
  id: 10,
  value: "Extra stuff"
}

const myArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "Val 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "Val 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "Val 3"
  },
]
const newArray = [...myArray.slice(0, 1), { ...myArray[1], ...{id: myObj.id}}, ...myArray.slice(2)]
console.log(newArray);
```

**OR**

Implement a good [deep copy](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-shallow-and-deep-copy-of-a-class/) logic. Copy the entire array to a new variable and update the id od the object at index 1.

```js
const myObj = {
  id: 10,
  value: "Extra stuff"
}

const myArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "Val 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "Val 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "Val 3"
  },
]
// My bad deep copy logic
const newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArray));
newArray[1].id = myObj.id;
console.log(newArray);
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: _"...updating its ID only"_

Comment: I hope my updated answer meets the requirement.

Comment: getting close @Nitheesh, thanks for your help. Need to update the id only, value remains the same

Comment: _"I hope..."_ - How about you test your answer before you post it as such? - No, it does not what OP asks for.

Comment: @NorbertGirch Can you please clarify your question. Right now a `Array[1].id = ...` would be enough to solve it...

Comment: @Andreas update the id value of the array with the object's id. Also need to preserve the original array

Comment: @NorbertGirch can you check my updated answer?

Comment: This is brilliant @Nitheesh!

Comment: Isn't it redundant to recreate the whole array instead of updating a single item with the index? And also using `...{id: myObj.id}` is not necessary since you can just use `id: myObj.id`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz that will update the original array.

Comment: @Nitheesh But it will not update the whole array. Only some of the properties of the object at index 2.

Comment: Four times `...` + two `.slice()` calls... Why don't you just clone the complete array and then do a `clone[1].id = myObj.id`?

Comment: @Andreas That I have done in the second part of my solution. First part is about fixing the current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread operator ([`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) if you want only to update the id (or any other specific properties)

And also try not to use variable names such as `Array` to avoid any potential conflicts.

```js
const myObj = {
  id: 10,
  value: "Extra stuff"
}

const myArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "Val 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "Val 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "Val 3"
  },
]

// Find the index of the item with ID=2
const indexOfId2 = myArray.findIndex(item => item.id === 2)

myArray[indexOfId2] = {...myArray[indexOfId2], id: myObj.id}

console.log(myArray)
```